# How to compare map[string]interface{} 's value string or not

Tags: api, go, controller, beego

> How to compare map[string]interface{} 's value string or not

```
m3 := map[string]interface{}{
"something":1,
"brawba":"Bawrbawr",
}

for key, value := range m3{
    if(reflect.TypeOf(value) == string or not){
        ... // here
    }else{
        ...
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KjxMaGsMTOR

Comment: What you want is a type assertion. See https://tour.golang.org/methods/15.

Comment: @AndySchweig please check my updated Question. I just want to know value is string or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to determine if the value is a `string`:

```
for key, value := range m3 {
    if s, ok := value.(string); ok {
        fmt.Printf("%s is the string %q\n", key, s)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s is not a string\n", key)
    }
}
```

Use reflect to determine if the value's base type string:

```
type mystring string

m3 := map[string]interface{}{
    "something": 1,
    "brawba":    "Bawrbawr",
    "foo":       mystring("bar"),
}

for key, value := range m3 {
    if reflect.ValueOf(value).Kind() == reflect.String {
        fmt.Printf("%s is a string with type %T and value %q\n", key, value, value)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s is not a string\n", key)
    }
}
```